# Combining and extending Ractive components

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am starting to use [Ractive](http://www.ractivejs.org/) and I would like to understand better how to make reusable components. It is quite easy to write a generic widget that can be used in different situations. My problem is that often the data in my applications does not come in the shape that the widget expects and I am not sure how to extend the widget to make it more application specific.

To make a concrete example, say I am writing a Ractive component to design a line chart. I would do something along the lines of

```
var Chart = Ractive.extend({
  template: chart,
  data: {
    points_to_path: function(points) {
      // whatever
    }
  }
});
```

with a template like

```
<svg>
  {{# points_to_path(points) }}
    <path d="{{ path }}" />
  {{/ end of path }}
</svg>
```

This component could be used like

```
var chart = new Chart({
  data: {
    points: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
  }
});
```

Now assume I actually need to use such a component. Probably my data does not come in the shape of an array of two-components arrays, like `points` above. Maybe I have something more like

```
[
  {
    date: 'aug 2011',
    value: 12.51
  },
  {
    date: 'sep 2011',
    value: 12.38
  },
  ...
]
```

So, what I would like to do is to make a more application specific `Chart` that accepts data in the above form. I do not see an easy way to do this with `Chart.extend`, because the reference to the `points` variable is hardcoded in `chart.html`.

In a framework like Backbone, views are nested, so I could just wrap the inner widget into a bigger view and in the external view define the logic for the data transformation. I am not quite sure how to go on from here in Ractive. Maybe I should have designed the widget in a different way from the start.

More generally, my problem is that I can write small components in Ractive, but I am not quite sure how to compose them into something bigger.

> What is the idiomatic way in Ractive to specialize or extend components? Or combine many components into a bigger application?

Comment: I don't work in ReactiveJS yet. However, GWT has a clean pattern of MVP driving views/widgets through a presenter, often known as an "activity". The activity holds business logic, fetching/messaging of data, start/stop type "work". I'm curious how this might fit in with RactiveJS myself. I'm guessing that its tempting to connect a lot of widgets together using Ractive, but it may be smarter to decouple the views a bit.

Comment: MVP in JS: http://neovibrant.com/2011/08/03/mvp-with-javascript/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple of possible solutions. I'm not sure what would qualify as idiomatic - generally, Ractive's philosophy is 'if it works, it's the right solution!' - I'm the author, but I'll leave it to the community to decide over time what is idiomatic.

### 1. Passing in functions at initialisation

If you were using d3 to create a scatterplot, typically you would do something like this:

```js
d3.select( 'circle' ).data( points )
     .enter().append( 'circle' )
       .attr( 'cx', function ( d ) { return d.x; })
       .attr( 'cy', function ( d ) { return d.y; })
       .attr( 'r', 5 );
```

In other words, for each *<del>datum</del>* item in the array, we've supplied a function that extracts the value we need to plot its x and y position.

The Ractive equivalent would be to specify a function when initialising the component:

```html
<!-- the template -->
<svg>
  <path d='{{ points_to_path(points) }}'/>
</svg>
```

```js
// let's create a chart component that assumes we get an array
// of points with an `x` and a `y` property
var Chart = Ractive.extend({
  template: chart,
  data: {
    points_to_path: function(points) {
      // is there a 'normalise' function? If so, normalise
      // the data we've been given
      if ( var normalise = this.get( 'normalise' ) ) {
        points = points.map( normalise );
      }

      // turn a normalised `{x: x, y: y}` point into 'x,y'
      var pointToString = function ( point ) {
        return point.x + ',' + point.y;
      };

      // create the SVG path
      return 'M' + points.map( pointToString ).join( ' ' );
    }
  }
});

// now, we need to create a function that tells the Chart
// component how to deal with the data we're about to give it
var chart = new Chart({
  data: {
    points: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]],
    normalise: function ( point ) {
      return { x: point[0], y: point[1] };
    }
  }
});
```

So if you had an array of points with `date` and `value` properties, you'd just pass a `normalise` function (or `normalize` if you prefer American spelling...) that returned `{x: point.date, y: point.value}` or whatever.

(Of course, you could overwrite the whole `points_to_path` function instead if that was easier.)

### 2. Using partials

An alternative would be to use different partials in different situations:

```html
<!-- widget template -->
<h2>This is a widget</h2>
<div class='contains-dynamic-contents'>
  {{>inner}}
</div>
```

```js
var widget = new Widget({
  el: 'widgetContainer',
  partials: {
    inner: '<p>This paragraph will appear inside the div</p>'
  }
});
```

This gives you a lot of freedom, but the line chart example is probably more cumbersome to adapt.

### Inline components

The first method would also work with [inline components](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/wiki/Components) - this example assumes you're using the development ([0.3.8-pre](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/tree/0.3.8/build)) version, which will be released soon:

```js
Ractive.components.linechart = Chart;
```

```html
<div class='application'>
  <h1>This is a chart</h1>
  <linechart points='{{someData}}' normalise='{{someNormaliseFunction}}'/>
</div>
```

(Protip: you could specify a default `normalise` function with `Chart.data.normalise = someFunction`.)

The second method is a little trickier - you would have to dynamically switch out the partial on initialisation:

```js
Chart = Ractive.extend({
  beforeInit: function () {
    this.partials.inner = ( someCondition ? thisPartial : thatPartial );
  },
  // ...
});
```

Sorry for the epic length of this response, hope the answer you wanted was in here somewhere!

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer. I briefly considered your first solutions, and I am not sure it scales well. Ideally, someone else my have written the `chart` component. Nesting the views, as in Backbone, gives you the flexibility to put an adapter in between your data and the target widget, even if the creator of the target widget did not think of putting a `normalise` function. Think it like typeclasses in Haskell, that are more flexible than interfaces because they can be retrofitted on an existing type.

Comment: Components, instead, look like a more flexible approach to the issue. I am having a look to see if this works well in my case, in particular it is not clear to me right now if a ractive can transform data before passing it into a component. I hope not to end in the hell of transclusions, isolate scopes and so on... :-)